# Java: if statement can be simplified (box contains point)

Tags: java, if-statement, compiler-warnings, simplify

I have the following statement to check if a Vector2D is within a box, and IntelliJ gives me a warning: "if statement can be simplified".

```
if(point.x < minX || point.x > maxX || point.y < minY || point.y > maxY)
    return false;
```

How can I simplify this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't see any possible simplification. I would just ignore the warning.

---

**Update:** However, if you method look like this:

```
if(point.x < minX || point.x > maxX || point.y < minY || point.y > maxY)
    return false;
return true;
```

You might change it to this:

```
return !(point.x < minX || point.x > maxX || point.y < minY || point.y > maxY);
```

Or even:

```
return point.x >= minX && point.x <= maxX && point.y >= minY && point.y <= maxY;
```

I don't know if this is "simplified" for humans.

Comment: This was indeed the case. I was lookig for a simplification inside the if clause. That's why I couldn't find it. I went with your last suggestion; it made more sense to me.

Answer (score 5):

Whenever IntelliJ warns of a possible simplification, it often offers to perform the simplification (by clicking the yellow light bulb). What happens if you do that?

Comment: There was no lightbulb in my version, but there was a clickable tool tip. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would just do this.

return !(point.x < minX || point.x > maxX || point.y < minY || point.y > maxY);

and it would remove the warning.

Answer (score 0):

Try separating it into two if statements: one for "x" coordinates, one for "y".

```
if(point.x < minX || maxX < point.x)
    return false;
else if(point.y < minY || maxY < point.y)
    return false;
```

Comment: This is not equivalent to what OP is asking.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try something like this:

```
return new Rectangle(minX, maxX, minY, maxY).contains(point);
```

As far as simplifying from a boolean algebra perspective, you must be looking for Martin's answer. In fact, you don't even need to simplify it because the compiler will automatically do it for you. For example, `!(a && b)` will simplify to `!a || !b` because it is quicker to check each variable separately as opposed to creating a temp variable and check the value of that.